# LLVM: Updating a Data structure at runtime

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I want to store data about each stack memory that is being allocated and changed.

To do so, I thought I'd need a data structure of some sort in which I can store the related data, such as the value of the local variable, and any change of it, e.g. before a `store` instruction.

Moreover, I should be able to check the value with the one saved in the data structure before any read of the local variable (e.g. `load` instruction).

If we assume that the IR looks like this

```
%1 = alloca i32, 
[...]
%20 = store i32 0, %1
```

I need to change the above code to look like the below

```
%18 = call __Checking
%19 = <storing the return value from __Checking into a data structure>
%20 = store i32 0, %1
```

My problem is I cannot figure out how to store the returned value from the library called `__Checking` into a `StructType` I defined at the beginning.

My relevant code

```
if (StoreInst *SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)){
   Value* newValue = IRB.CreateCall(....);
   Type* strTy[] = { Type::getInt64Ty(m.getContext()),                                                                              
                     Type::getInt64Ty(m.getContext()) };
   Type* t = StructType::create(strTy);
}
```

Comment: the posted IR is incomplete and has mistakes/typos in it

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any specific information on the type returned by `__Checking` (or even where does `__Checking` come from) and the internals of the `StructType`, so I'm going to suggest to abstract that behaviour away in a [runtime library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library) (most likely in C).

This will allow you to setup function calls in those parts of the IR that you require to store (or compare, etc.) a value. The function(s) would take as arguments the value and the `StructType` (and anything else required) and perform the desired action in plain C (e.g. store the value).

For example, using part of your posted IR (names prefixed with `myruntime_` should be defined in your runtime library):

```
%0 = alloca %myruntime_struct
[...]
%18 = call @__Checking
%19 = call @myruntime_storevalue(%2, %18, /* other arguments? */)
%20 = store i32 0, %1
```